# Command Object with generics

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that has a `Command Object` that uses generics like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/first")
public class MyFirstController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ADifferentDTO doSomething(RequestDTO<MyStringObject> requestDTO, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

            requestDTO.getSomeObject(); // ERROR HERE


            //.. do something
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. I'm assuming it does not working because of Type Erasure in Java. Is there a way I can have the Command Object use a generic?
Here is what some of the other classes might look like.

```
public class RequestDTO<T> {

    private T someObject;
    // some other objects here as well that are from a submitted form (not listed)


    public void setSomeObject(T someObject){
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    public T getSomeObject(){
        return someObject;
    }
}

public class MyStringObject {
    private String someString;

    public MyStringObject(String someString){
        this.someString = someString;
    }
    // getter and setter
}


public class MyIntegerObject {
    private Integer someInteger;
    private Integer anotherInteger;

    public MyIntegerObject(Integer someInteger, Integer anotherInteger){
        this.someInteger = someInteger;
        this.anotherInteger = anotherInteger;
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

The error I get:

`java.lang.Object cannot be cast to com.test.MyStringObject`

Of course if I change my `RequestDTO` to only use a `MyStringObject` it works fine.

```
public class RequestDTO {

    private MyStringObject someObject;
    // some other objects here as well that are from a submitted form (not listed)


    public void setSomeObject(MyStringObject someObject){
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    public MyStringObject getSomeObject(){
        return someObject;
    }
}
```

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: How does your controller know how to construct RequestDTO<MyStringObject> from what whatever passed from the client side?

Comment: If you're looking at a compiler error then type erasure is not involved.

Comment: @LewBloch it's a runtime error

Comment: @MinhKieu It doesn't know how to construct it

Comment: Then what's being passed in is not  a `MyStringObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is because of type erasure.

Probably the simplest solution is to create a RequestDTO subclasses parameterized with each of your My*Object and use it as a Command Object class.

Given your example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44423504Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44423504Application.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/first")
    public static class MyFirstController {

        public static class MyStringRequestDTO extends RequestDTO<MyStringObject> {}

        public static class MyIntegerRequestDTO extends RequestDTO<MyIntegerObject> {}

        @PostMapping(value = "/something")
        public String doSomething(@ModelAttribute MyStringRequestDTO/*MyIntegerRequestDTO*/ requestDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestDTO);
        }
    }

    public static class RequestDTO<T> {
        private T someObject;
        // getter and setter
    }

    public static class MyStringObject {
        private String someString;

        public MyStringObject() { } // required since another non-default ctor is present.

        public MyStringObject(String someString){
            this.someString = someString;
        }

        // getter and setter
    }

    public static class MyIntegerObject {
        private Integer someInteger;
        private Integer anotherInteger;

        public MyIntegerObject() { } // required since another non-default ctor is present.

        public MyIntegerObject(Integer someInteger, Integer anotherInteger){
            this.someInteger = someInteger;
            this.anotherInteger = anotherInteger;
        }
        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

Then it works fine:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080/first/something?someObject.someInteger=23&someObject.anotherInteger=42'
{"someObject":{"someInteger":23,"anotherInteger":42}}%

$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080/first/something?someObject.someString=test'                            
{"someObject":{"someString":"test"}}%
```

Comment: Wow, I'm a bit surprised it was that easy! Thank you! Quick question, what I don't understand is how a class extending a parameterized class fixes the type erasure problem. So `MyStringRequestDTO` is known to be a MyStringObject even though the  "extends RequestDTO<MyStringObject>" will not be resolved to a MyStringObject at runtime?

Comment: Well shortly, it is a way for compiler to store a type information within the `.class` file, since we're stated that T = MyStringObject, so it will be available at runtime. Try to run following snippet `System.out.println(MyStringRequestDTO.class.getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
System.out.println(new RequestDTO<MyStringObject>().getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());` and you'll see that actual type is present in the output.

Comment: Another way to see what is stored in class files is to use javap command passing classfile to it. For example above it is look like `public class com.stackoverflow.so44423504.MyStringRequestDTO extends com.stackoverflow.so44423504.RequestDTO<com.stackoverflow.so44423504.MyStringObject>` all type information is preserved.